What are the differences between mantle plume magmatism vs non-plume magmatism?
What are the differences between mantle plume magmatism vs non-plume magmatism?
Is there any chemical or mineralogical differences?

The main difference between the 2 types of magmatism is that a plume forms a hotspot in one specific place e.g. the Canary Islands. The oceanic crust that forms the islands is gradually moving North whiles the hotspot stays in it's place. That is way the oldest islands are in the North whiles current eruptions are in the South.
Non-plume magmatism is mainly 2 processes.
Due to subduction of of oceanic crust under another. This causes the subducted slap to melt and turn into lava because of the temperature of depth (note that low angle subduction doesn't always cause vulcanism). The other cause for non-plume magmatism are mid ocean ridges, where the separation of lithosphere causes decompression of the magma causing it to melt.
Also note that many hotspots are located close to mid oceanic ridges.
As for mineralogy, I'm not as sure, and it's much more diverse I believe. Mid oceanic ridges are chiefly composed of basalts (MORB) which are mainly plagioclase and olivine. As for magmas from subduction, the original rock has a lot to do with the mineralogy of the rock(s) that was subducted as well as the conditions it forms in. Magmas from plumes I think have higher content of iron because they form at lower depths.
